# Can Model communicate directly to the Data Access Layer?

Tags: c#, mvvm

Sorry if im asking the question wrong but here is an example:

```cs
public class Person : BaseModel {

    // somne properties like username, password, isLoggedIn


    public Person(SomeDataService dataService){...}

    public bool Login(){

       var result = dataService.TryToLogin(this.username, this.password);

      // do some stuff with result

    }

}
```

Some people says it is acceptable but some them says not, so I don't know what is right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are legitimate to use any kind of code that works for you, MVVM is just a convention that should help you to code better and quicker, but if it doesn't work for you and there is no 3rd party (like your employer) that enforces this requests you are free to do whatever works the best for you.

Speaking of MVVM, this class above should be a Model, and if you want to respect the MVVM convention you can't do what you did, it should contain just plain properties. But as I said above someone must choose whether he wants to use MVVM at all, so if you haven't decided to stick to the MVVM convention you can use this code, just count on that it may be a bit confusing if you need someone else to work on that code too.